# Vim: search and highlight but do not jump

Tags: search, vim

The [super star (<kbd>*</kbd>)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#star) key in Vim will search for the word under the cursor and jump forward to the next match. The user can jump to the next matches with the <kbd>n</kbd> key. If `hlsearch` is enabled, it will also highlight the matches.

I want to be able to press <kbd>*</kbd> and get the highlighted matches and be able to navigate the matches using the <kbd>n</kbd> key. However, I do **not** want Vim to jump to the next match when <kbd>*</kbd> is pressed, it should remain on the current word. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: An alternative is to split (`:sp`) the window and then perform the super start (`*`) search in the new window. That gives you the same 'info' effectively and similarly preserves your original cursor location.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I would map:

```
nnoremap * *``
```

Works exactly like you want, except that it adds a jump in the jump list. To prevent that you need:

```
nnoremap * :keepjumps normal! mi*`i<CR>
```

Comment: by "blink" I meant that it will blink, if the next matched word is out of the screen...

Comment: The second one doesn't work for me, when I press * it says: "E169: Command too recursive"

Comment: Are you sure you typed nnoremap and not just nmap ?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same as it says.

Comment: You need to use `normal!` in this second one. `normal` is to `normal!` as `nmap` is to `nnoremap`

Comment: I also had to modify this to: `nnoremap * :keepjumps normal! mi*\`i<CR>` because, for some reason, `\`\`` didn't work as expected.

Comment: Better way `nnoremap * *#`, avoid blinking

Comment: Hi, what does "it adds a jump in the jump list" mean?

Comment: @KeithSmiley However, it will still change the position of the current cursor while keepjumps, any idea?

Comment: I find that @name5566's starsearch can keep the position of the current cursor like the behavior of the star key is not be changed.

Comment: First `normal` should be changed to `normal!`. Second, keepjumps will not set the `` ` `` mark. I use ```nnoremap * m`:keepjumps normal! *``<cr>```. An slightly different way is to do ```nnoremap * m`:keepjumps normal! *<cr>`` ```

Comment: This doesn't do what is desired. Even though it moves the cursor back to the original location the screen view might shift compared to the original screen view if the next match is outside the current view.

Answer (score 12):

I found this works pretty well, there's no blink and it doesn't need an intermediate register.

```
nnoremap <silent> * :let @/= '\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>' <bar> set hls <cr>
```

Or if you want the `g*` behavior:

```
nnoremap <silent> g* :let @/=expand('<cword>') <bar> set hls <cr>
```

Comment: This one is the superior solution in my option. No jumping, no adding to the jumplist and nothing is added to any copy register that I might need later.

Answer (score 7):

The best solution:

1. don't add a jump to the jump list
2. the behavior of the star key is not be changed

so, try the plugin:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4335

Much better than:

```
" a jump adds to the jump list
nnoremap * *``
" I got a dead loop on macvim
nnoremap * :keepjumps normal *``<cr>
" the behavior is changed
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>* :let @/='\<<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>\>'<CR>:set hls<CR>
```

Comment: Great plugin, another useful feature is you can use `*` to search for text that selected in Visual mode. The downside is, it moves your cursor to the beginning of word, if you were in the middle of the word.

Comment: Third option works best for me. It highlights and both screen and cursor don't move.

Comment: how is the behavior changed? the third option seems to work great for me, whereas the other (non plugin) options on this question are bad (specifically variants of the second option can reset the highlighted word into the middle of the screen which is jarring)

Answer (score 7):

I haven't seen this one yet:

`nmap <silent> * "syiw<Esc>: let @/ = @s<CR>`

It's very short and does not involve jumping around which can result in blinking.

Explanation: copy the word under cursor to `s` register and then set the search register (`/`) to the content of `s` register. The search register is not writeable directly, that's why the let is necessary and hence the `silent` to keep vim's command line clean.

Comment: It works pretty well for me, no blinking issue. Screen stands still.

Comment: Same, no blinking/jumping issues

Comment: Nice, I changed it slightly to yank to the unnamed (working) register
nmap <silent> * yiw<Esc>: let @/ = @""<CR>

Answer (score 5):

I have the following in my .vimrc, which I think works better than the other alternatives:

```
" Put word under cursor into search register and highlight
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>* :let @/='\<<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>\>'<CR>:set hls<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>* :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy:let @/=substitute(
  \escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>:set hls<CR>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the current view and add the search to the history, try this [not so efficient] solution:

```
noremap * msHmt`s*`tzt`s
```

It is using the marks `s` (save) and `t` (top).

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution came to my mind: put `map * *#` in `.vimrc` file (it will blink though).

Comment: why not *`` so the cursor go back exactly at the same positon

Comment: @mb14 does it bring any benefit `#` doesn't have?

Comment: it works ;-) *# move your cursor to the beginning of the word if you were in the middle and worst, if you set nowrapscan and do a search from the last occurence of a word *# move you to the previous word (because * didn't jump anywhere)

Comment: both `*#` and *`` has blinking issue.

Comment: It leaves you in backwards search mode though. So for instance, your `n` and `N` keys will be reversed.

Answer (score 3):

Many answers here outline rather simple mappings that work well for common cases, but may have side effects (like flickering by jumping back and forth) or lack robustness (may break if some regexp characters are defined as keyword characters).

If you're looking for a robust implementation and don't mind installing a plugin, you can choose from a plethora of alternatives, many of which also offer additional search-related improvements:

- My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) changes the `*` command, extends it to visual selections, and offers optional auto-searching of the word under the cursor.
- [star search](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4335) changes the behavior of `*` to not jump to the next match, and includes the visual search from the next plugin
- [vim-visual-star-search](https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search) provides searching of the visual selection
- [visualstar.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2944) provides searching of the visual selection
- [select & search](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4819) can use either `n/N` or `*` in the visual selection, and can avoid jumping.
- [vim-asterisk](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5059) provides a `z*` mapping that also doesn't jump, visual `*`, more intuitive smartcase handling, and can keep the cursor position when jumping (like `,*`)
- [searchant.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5404) hooks into the built-in search commands and provides a separate highlighting for the match last jumped to.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
nnoremap <silent><expr> * v:count ? '*'
      \ : ':silent execute "keepjumps normal! *" <Bar> call winrestview(' . string(winsaveview()) . ')<CR>'
nnoremap <silent><expr> g* v:count ? 'g*'
      \ : ':silent execute "keepjumps normal! g*" <Bar> call winrestview(' . string(winsaveview()) . ')<CR>'
```

Edit: Recent Vim has `<Cmd>` mapping, so you can use below to avoid CmdlineEnter/Leave to be fired.

```
nnoremap <expr> * v:count ? '*'
      \ : '<Cmd>silent keepjumps normal! *<CR><Cmd>call winrestview(' .. string(winsaveview()) .. ')<CR>'
nnoremap <expr> g* v:count ? 'g*'
      \ : '<Cmd>silent keepjumps normal! g*<CR><Cmd>call winrestview(' .. string(winsaveview()) .. ')<CR>'
```

Pros:

- No flickering.
- Jump list remains unchanged.
- With a count, it invokes original `*`; you can use `1*` if you miss the original `*`.
- Marks and registers are untouched.
- Using original `*`, its behavior is almost identical with `*` (except for jumping).
  This means `'smartcase'` is ignored as `*` do.
- No need to install plugins.

Comment: Here is a [Neovim version](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43660/25982). Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are good, particularly @rodrigo's, but I wanted to write a solution that preserves scroll position and does so without affecting any of the marks.

This works for me:

```
function! StarPositionSave()
  let g:star_position_cursor = getpos('.')
  normal! H
  let g:star_position_top = getpos('.')
  call setpos('.', g:star_position_cursor)
endfunction
function! StarPositionRestore()
  call setpos('.', g:star_position_top)
  normal! zt
  call setpos('.', g:star_position_cursor)
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> * :call StarPositionSave()<CR>*:call StarPositionRestore()<CR>
```

Putting `normal! *` in the function directly doesn't seem to work, as (at least in neovim) it suppresses search highlighting from being triggered (as if `:nohlsearch` was run).

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer because I found the other answers either, centered the line in the view (which I found distracting), or seemed overly complicated.

The following command works well for me:

```
noremap * :let @/ = "\\<<C-r><C-w>\\>"<cr>:set hlsearch<cr>
```

It simply sets the pattern to the whole word under the cursor and then turns on (or updates) the highlighting for the search pattern.

- NOTE: It doesn't modify the search history (which I prefer but might not be quite what you want).

Answer (score 1):

just do

```
nnoremap * *N
nnoremap # #n
```

works with this http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4335 too like so:

```
vnoremap * :<C-u>call VisualStarSearchSet('/')<CR>/<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>N
vnoremap # :<C-u>call VisualStarSearchSet('?')<CR>?<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>n
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `*` we have

```
[I ..................... it shows where the word under the cursor appears
```

I also have some useful lines on my vimrc that can, maybe, help you

```
" When double click a word vim will hightlight all other ocurences
" see CountWordFunction()
" [I shows lines with word under the cursor
nnoremap <silent> <2-LeftMouse> :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>:CountWord<cr>
nnoremap <Leader>* :let @/='\V\<'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<cr>:set hls<cr>:CountWord<cr>

if !exists('*CountWordFunction')
    fun! CountWordFunction()
        try
            let l:win_view = winsaveview()
            exec "%s/" . expand("<cword>") . "//gn"
        finally
            call winrestview(l:win_view)
        endtry
    endfun
endif

command! -nargs=0 CountWord :call CountWordFunction()
cnoreabbrev cw CountWord
nnoremap <F3> :CountWord<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

`nnoremap <silent> ml :<c-u>let @/ = '\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'\|set hlsearch<CR>wb`

---

and if you want a visual mode one:

```
function SetSearchVisualSelection()
    let clipboard_original_content=@"
    normal gvy " this overwrites clipboard
    let raw_search=@"
    let @/=substitute(escape(raw_search, '\/.*$^~[]'), "\n", '\\n', "g")
    let @"=clipboard_original_content
endfunction
vnoremap ml :call SetSearchVisualSelection()<CR>:set hlsearch<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed, mapped it to `-` which I was not using

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
:match ErrorMsg /SearchPattern/
```

which will highlight *SearchPattern* in the file with the colors from *ErrorMsg* highlight profile. To define a custom highlight profile you can do:

```
:highlight MyHighlightProfile ctermbg=green guibg=green
```

and then use it for searching:

```
:match MyHighlightProfile /SearchPattern/
```