# Vim, how to change the default behaviour of * key?

Tags: vim

When I press * button on a word, vim searches it and moves cursor to the beginning of next match of that word. How can I change this functionality in such way: when I press * to a word, it searches for it, colors the matched words, I can move to next word by pressing n, **but it does not automatically move cursor to the beginning of next match**. I just need vim to color the word on which I press * and to navigate on next and previous matches of that word using n and N.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256697/vim-search-and-highlight-but-do-not-jump

Comment: What do you want? That `*` moves to the first match or that it doesn't? The first behavior is the default while the second sounds more like `/<cword>`.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer that behaviour too.  I've had this in my vimrc for ages:

```
noremap * *N
noremap # #N
```

`#` works the same as `*` but in reverse

Comment: when I click on some word the cursor position is not changed but the second match of that word appears on screen if it is near, how to disable that too?

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer it that way. You can use my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) or one of the alternatives listed on the plugin page.