# Vim search for last edited word

Tags: vim

While editing code in Vim I constantly find myself doing the same thing. I will move to a word and press 'cw' or 'ciw' to edit the word. I then want to move to the next occurrence of the word I just edited. '*' won't work because it will move me to the next occurrence of the new word (not the old one).

E.g:

In the code below my cursor is on the first occurrence of 'foo' and I want to change it to bar. I press 'cw' and write 'bar'. I then want to move to the next occurrence of 'foo' so that I can press '.' to change it. Pressing '*' will move me to the next 'bar' instead of 'foo'. The only way I know around this is to either change all 'foo's with a replace command which might not be what I want, or press '*' to move to the next 'foo' and then '#' to go back to store 'foo' as the search term so I can press 'n' to move forward. Is there anyway to set the search term without jumping to the next word (set the word that 'n' goes to without going anywhere)?

```
function(){
    var foo = 'blah';
    foo = 'blah';
    foo = 'blah';
}
```

-->

```
function(){
    var bar = 'blah';
    foo = 'blah';
    foo = 'blah';
}
```

Comment: Do you know the `c` flag of the search command, i.e. `:%s/foo/bar/gc`? Sounds to me like a good solution to your problem, but not really answering your question.

Comment: I think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256697/vim-search-and-highlight-but-do-not-jump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Keep it simple and use undo

- Use `u` to undo your change
- Search via `*`
- Redo your change via `<c-r>`

Vim has a nice undo system so make sure you take advantage of it. See `:h undo`.

#### Unamed register approach

This is the same as @Ingo Karkat approach. I will quickly repeat it here:

```
/<c-r>"<cr>
```

See `:h quotequote` and `:h c_ctrl-r`.

#### Substitution

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
```

The `:s` command can also take a range so you can visually select lines a do a substitution over just those lines. The `c` flag stands for `confirm` which will make `:s` ask before each substitution. See `:h :s` and `:h :s_flags`.

#### Use `.` and the `gn` motion

- Search for your pattern via `/` or `*`.
- Change the pattern text via the `c` operator over the motion `gn`. e.g. `cgnbaz<esc>`
- Just keep hitting `.` to repeat.

See `:h gn` and `:h .` for more information.

*Note*: `gn` motion is available starting in version 7.4

Answer (score 3):

The text replaced by commands like `ciw` is put into the default register `""`. Text just entered is in the special register `".`. Therefore, you can search (for the former) with:

```
/<C-r>"<CR>
```

Note that this is only the quick 99% solution; to work with all sorts of characters, you'd need to escape:

```
/\V\C<C-r>=escape(@@, '\')<CR><CR>
```

#### Plugin alternative

Since I often have exactly the same use case as you describe in your question (replacing a short text, then re-applying that for next matches), I've written the [ChangeGlobally plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4321); it provides a `gc{motion}` mapping as a replacement of `c` that then reapplies the change in the rest of the line / buffer (for `[count]` occurrences).

Comment: Also it should be in the "small delete" register `-`

Answer (score 1):

I would search for `foo`, e.g.

```
/foo
```

then when I press 'n' it finds the next instance of `foo` - `n` searches for the next instance of what it found.

You can then do `cw` and change to `bar` and pressing `esc` then `n` will take you to the next `foo` without having to go back then forwards.

Comment: I read it as they hadn't searched for `foo` in the first place