# Hightlight cursor word in (Neo)vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I was getting the cursor word as: `noremap <leader>h *N`, but this moves the screen. What I want is:

- Highlights the `<cword>`; and
- Not move the screen, nor the cursor.

Here is my system: Linux, running neovim v0.4.3 with python2&3 support.

OBS: I know about the plugin `inkarkat/vim-mark` but I got [some errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWMY2.png) and it is much more than I need.

I tried using the builtin `matchadd`, but could not enter the `<cword>` (it interprets the string literally), and within brackets it considered it a regex.

[image: my vimrc]

Comment: `I tried using the builtin matchadd, but could not enter the <cword>` Do `expand('<cword>')`

Comment: To make my Mark.vim plugin work, you need to install my [ingo-library plugin dependency](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) (it's now also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/inkarkat/ingo-library)) as well. But I agree, this plugin would be overkill for your use case; my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) (or any of the alternatives at that plugin page, or in the duplicate question) would be better suited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then here is the answer to your question:

[ViM: Search and highlight but do not jump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256697/vim-search-and-highlight-but-do-not-jump)

Comment: Solution from Jeet made the trick.
Thank you